# Altering ownership on Redshift table throws "must be superuser to change owner"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, privileges

I'm having issues with some simple Redshift command.

The problem I'm facing is with altering the ownership of a table, here's more detail.

In our Redshift cluster, in one of the databases we have, as an admin user, I've created a schema and group adding 2 users to it:

```
create schema materialized_views_staging;
create group mv_owners with user paul, ana;
```

Where `paul` and `ana` are 2 users that our data analysts use to access the Redshift cluster.

I then updated permissions on the schema as:

```
grant usage on schema materialized_views_staging TO etl;
grant all on schema materialized_views_staging to group mv_owners;
grant usage on schema materialized_views_staging to group mv_owners;
alter default privileges in schema materialized_views_staging grant all on tables to group mv_owners;
```

Where `etl` is a user that we use to run daily ETL jobs.

After running all of the above `paul` created a table:

```
create table materialized_views_staging.hj_insights (idd varchar, amount int);
```

Now, we need to change the table ownership so that the daily ETL can insert data into the table as it runs.

At this point `paul` is the owner of the `hj_insights` table. As per the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Privileges.html), the owner  (or a superuser) of an object can query, modify, or grant privileges on the object. However, when `paul` runs the below:

```
ALTER TABLE materialized_views_staging.hj_insights OWNER TO etl;
```

He's getting the error:

```
[2020-10-29 10:19:57] [42501][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: must be superuser to change owner;
```

Which is in contrast with what the documentation is stating.

Can you spot anything in my process that is not correct? I'm quite sure I have set up all the necessary permissions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is for PostgreSQL. According to the comments, Amazon Redshift was modified so that this is not possible.**

Changing the ownership is different from granting a privilege, so the documentation you quote doesn't cover that.

[The PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) states:

> You must own the table to use `ALTER TABLE`. [...] To alter the owner, you must also be a direct or indirect member of the new owning role, and that role must have `CREATE` privilege on the table's schema.

So you must be both `paul` (or a member of `paul`) **and** `etl` (or a member of `etl`) to execute the command. Superusers can of course always change ownership.

That last sentence must be a bit confusing, so let me explain. In PostgreSQL there is no distiction between users and groups, both are “roles”. So like you can be a member of a group, you can also be a member of a user.

So one way to make this ownership change work is to (temporarily) make one user a member of the other:

```
GRANT etl TO paul;
```

Now if you are `paul`, you are a member of `etl` at the same time, and you will be allowed to run the statement.

Comment: hey thanks for this. So, `etl` is actually part of `mv_owners` group, my bad for not stating that above. I just ran a quick check to confirm this and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You must have misunderstood me: you must be both `etl` and `paul` (or a member of them) to change the ownership. It is irrelevant what group `etl` and `paul` belong to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. How could I be both `etl` and `paul` if `etl` and `paul` are 2 users with passwords that are used to connect to the cluster?

Comment: I understand that it is confusing. I have extended the answer in a way that will hopefully make things clear.

Comment: thanks Laurenz, now it's more clear and I can follow where you going with that. Unfortunately, the command you provided doesn't work on Redshift `[42601][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "etl"`

Comment: Then you probably cannot change ownership on this hacked up version of PostgreSQL, since you cannot get superuser privileges.

Comment: Interesting. I thought this was a pretty simple use case, but apparently it's not. Thanks for helping anyway Laurenz.